# QtConcurrent::run right use

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I'm trying to use a function that records video by the selected time, so I use a signal to start it but the GUI stays block so I'm trying now to use `QtConcurrent::run` to do it in a separated thread. I have the class that records so I try to call it from the same class this way:

```
 void VideoProcessor::record(int index, int time, int frames, QString path){
           QFuture<void> future = QtConcurrent::run(recordAsync,index,time,frames, path);

}

void VideoProcessor::recordAsync(int index, int time, int frames, QString path)
{
     recording code ....

}
```

or from somewhere else like this:

```
void Controller::StartRecording(int index, int time, int frames, QString path)
{

    QFuture<void> future = QtConcurrent::run(&this->videoProcessor,record,index,time,frames, path);
    this->videoProcessor->record(index,time,frames,path);
}
```

but I it shows this error:

> error: no matching function for call to 'run(ab::VideoProcessor**,
>   <unresolved overloaded function type>, int&, int&, int&, QString&)'
>        QFuture<void> future = QtConcurrent::run(&this>videoProcessor,record,index,time,frames,
>   path);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should provide the pointer to the object and also the address of the class member function. If your function has parameters you can pass them at the end :

```
QFuture<void> future = QtConcurrent::run(this, &VideoProcessor::recordAsync, index, time, frames, path);
```

Comment: And from somewhere else as:
`QFuture<void> future = QtConcurrent::run(videoProcessor, &VideoProcessor::record,index,time,frames, path);`

Comment: @Nejat I quite this way to do it.